# Changing the logo for a sender in the iOS Mail app

Tags: email

Does anyone knows how to set the logo for a certain mail sender like the ones in the screenshot?

For example, the Apple logo for the "Apple" email.

[image]

Comment: this should really belong on a different stack exchange site

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the built-in mail app on iOS
2. Open an email from the sender whose image you want to change
3. On the right, where the email is displayed, tap the name of the send (top-middle of screen).
4. When the contact screen opens, scroll down to the bottom of window. Tap 'Create new contact' at the bottom, or if that option isn't there, then tap 'Edit' in the top-right of the window.
5. Create or edit the contact and set the contact image to the image that you want to see by their messages.